# Shopify site is responsive on web browser but not iPhone

Tags: css, responsive-design, shopify

I've seen this topic on a few threads on StackOverflow but no answers that have helped. I'm working on the site thegldshop.com and it is supposedly responsive. When I resize my browser on my laptop, I see the mobile version of the site and also when I use Screenfly.

However, when I open the site on my iPhone (or any other mobile phone for that matter), the full site is displayed. I have added mobile-specific met
`<!-- Mobile Specific Metas -->
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

but still nothing. I'm a total beginner to all this so any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

May be u are missing any closing bracket check your all media queries brackets, safari is not closing bracket it self like other browser

Answer (score 0):

If you go to thegldshop.com, you get a site that is entirely contained inside an iframe and isn't mobile friendly.

```
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://the-gld-shop.myshopify.com/" frameborder="0" />
  <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>
```

But if you go to **www**.thegldshop.com (or the-gld-shop.myshopify.com, which redirects to www.thegldshop.com), you get a normal site (no iframes) that works fine on mobile.  Looks like you have some DNS and/or web site config issues.

Comment: Wow, that's a great find! Any idea on how I could fix this?

Comment: Without knowing what web server software you are using and what your DNS records look like, no.  I would post another question about it with as much detail as possible (e.g. your httpd.conf if using apache) and also find  the html file that contains that frameset.